# Content-Disposition doesn't accept a variable

Tags: php, header, content-disposition

I am trying to set the filename in the Content-Disposition as the $fileName variable, but when I do it like in the following piece of code, the format of the archive comes wrong, and the name comes as $fileName. If i leave the filename empty, it works, but the name comes as the default name of the page.

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['file'])){

$fileName = basename($filePath);
$filePath = $_GET['file'];

if(file_exists($filePath)){

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filePath');
    header('Content-Control: public');

    readfile($filePath);

    exit;

}else{

    echo 'no doc';
    
}}?>
```

Comment: Variables are only expanded inside double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: There are no HTTP header fields called "Content-Control" or "Content-Description".